# TFS 2010 Build Work Items in a Certain State

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We have been using TFS 2010 to manage work items and sprints for a while now and have recently added on a dedicated QA person. What I need to be able to do is to either create a build definition that I can run on a scheduled basis (Tuesdays at 9pm for instance) that will only build and/or deploy the Work Items that are in a State of "ReadyToDeploy". Or a way to get a list of files to push based on the TFS API.

My end goal is to have a way to automate the release process so that only the items that have passed QA are sent to our staging environment weekly. Then the customer or QA can approve that the items work in staging which is a mirror of production, and another process or build definition will deploy those items which will be in a different state.

I have modified the work items and work flows to accomplish the different states, but I am having an issue getting either a build of just the fixes or a list of all the files to push based on the state of the work item.

I am open to any ideas or solutions for this, the alternative is that I have to manage the list of files and manually push files every week and I am trying to get away from that.

Thanks,

Edit: The way we have it setup now, is that each developer has their own branch and own website, our software is server based and has to be run on a particular server. Our Trunk is linked to the main dev website. This is where QA initially does their testing to move an item to the ready to deploy status. When a dev is ready for QA they check in their changes in their branch and merge into the trunk. The builds are created off of the trunk at the moment. On our deployment nights I open up the trunk website in VS and do a publish then take those files compared against a list the developers have given me and ftp the compiled files to our production server.

Comment: I think you would have to have the devs only merge these work items into another branch that gets built. Auto merging X Y Z changesets would be a very dangerous game!

Comment: See the [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I am not aware of a way to tell a build to avoid certain changesets based on the state of an attached work item.

I think the only way you could achieve this would be to create a `Release` branch and perform a daily merge of changesets that are in the "ReadyToDeploy" state.  When you merge, you are able to cherry pick changesets, but they must be [contiguous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contiguous).  This means that you would have to perform multiple merges to get the `Release` branch into the appropriate condition.

We have operated something similar for many years and it works well for us.  Many people will tell you that it's bad practice, and it probably is, but that is for you to decide.

As for automating this for a build, I don't think it would be a trivial job.  The hardest part will be the merge.  You might think that there will be no conflicts as it is a one-way merge, but having done this for a number of years, I can tell you that conflicts do arise.

**Step By Step Explanation**

1. Create a branch off the `trunk` called `release`
2. When you want to do a deploy, merge from the `trunk` into `release`, but only cherry pick the `ReadyToDeploy` changesets.  This may take several merges as the changesets must be contiguous.
3. Fire off a build / deploy of the release branch.
4. Repeat steps 2 - 3 as your release schedule allows.

Comment: So here is what I have done.
Created a Branch Called Staging
I have a windows service I wrote to pull in tickets from our Help Desk (Zendesk) so I added some functionality into that to query for all Work Items that are in a ReadyToDeploy Status. From that list I get all changesets associated and save them to a list then sort them by ID. Next I loop through my list of changesets and check if Changes != null and do my merge. I get the status and check for conflicts and try and auto resolve any that I can. If the changeset merges into my staging branch successfully then I check it in.

Comment: Still Left to do, kick off a build and check for it's completion and then copy those changes to the staging server. Also update the ticket in zen desk to let the customer know that the item is in staging

Answer (score 0):

You could do something automatic, it would require an extensive bit of coding. It would also require a branching strategy so that, Dev, Staging, and Production all come from their own branches.

1. Set up a process that uses the TFS API to scan for items in that state
2. Use API to Traverse Items to get check ins attached
3. Use API to Get latest of source and target branch
4. Use API to Merge by change set (identified in #2) (this is non trivial, have to handle lots of cases, but merging should all be 1 way with no conflicts, so doable)
5. Use API to Check In
6. Kick off Compile Build
7. If Compile Build Successful kick off Publish Build

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is a major issue with this approach. Say you have two changesets: # 1 and 2. Both of them containing modification for the same file. Now changeset #2 contains its own changes plus changes from #1.
If you decide to pull in changeset 2 and skip #1 guess what's gonna happen. You are going to suck in changes from #1. This is obviously a problem.